# Memory effective Linear interpolation with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a 1D array (XYData), e.g.

```
$TE = array(
      "1"=>"20",
      "2"=>"30",
      "5"=>"50",
      "10"=>"90"
   )
```

I would like to create a memory effective PHP function which do the Linear interpolation of the passed X value and return the corresponding Y value. e.g.

calling `function interpolate($TE,9.5)`
then it should return 86

Is there any way to avoid the array search  as the XYData set may be very long, say more then 100 points.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That doesn't look much like a 2-d array to me, it's only one-dimensional, key/value pairs.... given that it's a non-linear projection, you'll need to use a regression to calculate the intermediate values

Comment: Yes. this should be a 1D array.

Comment: http://blog.creativum.nl/2011/09/linear-interpolation-with-php/

Comment: Thank you @Hanky웃Panky, the example is returning the X value by providing the Y value, how can I do it in reverse? and make it a more memory effective code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot avoid looking at your array. To make it more efficient you have to restructure your data. Do this by recursively looking for the middle, and then split it at that point into two parts. For your short example you would get this:

```
$TER = array("2 and lower"  => array("1" => "20", 
                                     "2" => "30"),
             "5 and higher" => array("5" => "50",
                                     "8" => "100"));
```

No recursion is shown, and it really doesn't make any sense for such a small set of data, but when the dataset becomes large there's a clear advantage. It's basically a simple binary search tree.

But I have my doubts implementing it would be useful in this case. I'm not going to work it all out, you really should have 100.000 items or more to make this useful. If not, then just work through the array.